# Issue with putting static 3-rd DNS on CentOs 7

Tags: domain-name-system, centos7

I have a static IP configuration on my CentOs 7 network interface, configured 3 DNS servers, first two with public, third one with private IP address, but third one doesn't appear at /etc/resolve.conf. 
Here is my interface config file.

`[root@lb1 ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eno16777984
TYPE="Ethernet"
BOOTPROTO="static"
IPADDR="192.168.1.1"
NETMASK="255.255.255.0"
GATEWAY="192.168.1.254"
DNS1="8.8.8.8"
DNS2="8.8.4.4"
DNS3="192.168.1.10"
DEFROUTE="yes"
PEERDNS="yes"
PEERROUTES="yes"
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
NAME="eno16777984"
UUID="a40a179d-c2c4-4788-b68c-ed96ecac1da8"
DEVICE="eno16777984"
ONBOOT="yes"
NM_CONTROLLED="no"`

Comment: Why not just take it out of the device config file and put it in resolv.conf directly?  There's no need for recreating resolv.conf every time you restart your network or server if the configuration is static...

Comment: It is also solution, but also need to disable NetworkManager service. But seems like network script file doesn't support more then 2 NS's.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the issue with disabling it.  NM_CONTROLLED="no" means you aren't using it, for this interface anyway.

Comment: Yes, but if I'd be disable it NetworkManager will override my /etc/resolve.conf

Comment: If you disable network manager, what will be overwriting it besides you and your chosen text editor?  I have never managed resolv.conf any other way but directly except when using dhcp....

Comment: You are right, I forgot to write not after I'd.

Comment: @azatuni If necessary you can always `chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf` after your changes and nothing will touch it.